# Is there a webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback method in Swift 3 with Cocoa and WebKit?

Tags: cocoa, swift3, webkit, xcode8, macos-sierra

I have the following code inside Playgrounds in Xcode 8.* with Swift 3.2 and MacOS Sierra 10.12.*.  Is there still a webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback method in Swift 3.2 for Cocoa and WebKit because it doesn't come up with IntelliSense?

```
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport
import XCTest
import WebKit

var myWebView:WebView! = WebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 550, height: 300))

myWebView.mainFrame.loadHTMLString("<html><body><iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fvideos%2F10153231379946729%2F&width=500&show_text=false&height=280&appId\" width=\"500\" height=\"280\" style=\"border:none;overflow:hidden\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe></body></html>", baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myWebView
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```